# {alias} Имеется ли возможность использовать >, <, >>, +<, +>, +>>?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Собственно, суть вопроса в заголовке вопроса. Возникнут ли какие-либо траблы при использовании этих режимов в alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможность использовать есть, конечно:

```bsh
$ alias OMG='echo 42 > hi.txt'
$ OMG
$ cat hi.txt 
42
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.0(1)-release
```

Насчет траблов вопрос слишком общий. bash — это горящая земля, по ней надо идти помня все правила, чтоб не выстрелить в ногу.